# while loop on a map spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

i have this problem with a **mapType** in spark using scala API
for each session we are sending a map in which you can find the categories the user visited associated with the number of events in each  category

```
[ home & personal items > interior -> 1, vehicles > cars -> 1]
```

Not all the user visit the same number of categories so the size of the map changes based on the user_id

i need to calculate the number of session grouped by category 
in order to that i need to loop over the map and while its not it's not empty 
things i've tried before

```scala
while (size(col("categoriesRaw")) !== 0) {
    df.select(
        explode(col("categoriesRaw"))
    )
    .select(
        col("key").alias("categ"),
        col("value").alias("number_of_events")
    )
}
```

but i'm facing some errors like :

```
type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Booleansbt
```

Comment: Can you share sample dataframe?

Comment: @Kaushal something like:  StructField("sessionId", StringType, true),
   StructField("categoriesRaw", MapType(StringType, IntegerType, true), true),

Comment: can you share a sample data field?

Comment: @YayatiSule something like [ home & personal items > interior -> 1, vehicles > cars -> 1] 
[  vehicles > cars -> 3]

Comment: is your raw data in JSON format?   Like this over here [{"home_and_personal":{"interior":1},"vehicles":{"cars":1}}]

Comment: i'm reading a parquet file from amazon s3 datalake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the while loop. Anyway, you can check with the REPL that the expression you use as a condition is a `Column` and not a `Boolean`, hence the Exception.

```scala
> size(col("categoriesRaw")) !== 0
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (NOT (size(categoriesRaw) = 0))
```

Basically, this is an expression that needs to be evaluated by SparkSQL within a `where`, `select` or any other function that uses Columns.

Nevertheless, with your spark code you are almost there, you just need to add a `groupBy` to get where you want. Let's start by creating your data.

```scala
import spark.implicits._
val users = Seq( "user 1" -> Map("home & personal items > interior" -> 1,
                                 "vehicles > cars" -> 1), 
                 "user 2" -> Map("vehicles > cars" -> 3)) 
val df = users.toDF("user", "categoriesRaw")
```

Then, you don't need a while loop to iterate over all the values of the maps. `explode` does exactly that for you:

```scala
val explodedDf = df.select( explode('categoriesRaw) )
explodedDf.show(false)

+--------------------------------+-----+
|key                             |value|
+--------------------------------+-----+
|home & personal items > interior|1    |        
|vehicles > cars                 |1    |
|vehicles > cars                 |3    |
+--------------------------------+-----+
```

Finally, you can use groupBy add get what you want.

```scala
explodedDf
    .select('key as "categ", 'value as "number_of_events")
    .groupBy("categ")
    .agg(count('*), sum('number_of_events))
    .show(false)

+--------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
|categ                           |count(1)|sum(number_of_events)|
+--------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
|home & personal items > interior|1       |1                    |
|vehicles > cars                 |2       |4                    |
+--------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

NB: I was not sure if you wanted to count the sessions (1st column) or the events (2nd column) so I computed both.

Comment: oky let me explain myslef to you . i'm trying to do the while loop because when i do the explode function and then select (key) and value its only taking the first (key,value)not all of them... maybe the size of each Rawcategory changes from a user to another

Comment: It would greatly help if you could provide sample data and the expected output. This way we would understand better what you are trying tout do.

Comment: input: StructField("sessionId", StringType, true), StructField("categoriesRaw", MapType(StringType, IntegerType, true), true), the map is like : user 1  [ home & personal items > interior -> 1, vehicles > cars -> 1] user 2: [ vehicles > cars -> 3]

Comment: i'd like to do a loop that will loop over a map as long as not *empty* (because we dont know the exact size of each map) and *explode* ALL the key values of that map (because if i dont do a loop its only taking the first key value)

Comment: Can you add all this information in your question? It will help others with a similar problem as yours find a solution more easily. And people who want to help you will have all the info in one place.

Comment: I edited my answer with more details. Unless I did not understand your need, you can do it without the while loop.

Comment: ahhh great thank you i thought i need it to do a loop so it will explode all the (key,value) from the map thanks for your answer

Comment: You're welcome! If you are satisfied with the answer, could you accept it so as to let others know that the solution has been found?

Comment: i don't find where to do that

Comment: Right below the arrows to vote for an answer, you have a validate button that has the form of a "V". It's grey when you have not accepted any answer and turns green once you have clicked on it.